# Kubernetes AWS Load Balancer is Out of Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kops

I have deployed my spring boot  application to AWS Load Balancer with service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: and service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http; the application (pods and service) is running, but the Load Balancer is Out of Service with the message:

> Blockquote
> Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively. I have added readinessProbe and livenessProbe to no avail.